# Keycloak spring boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, keycloak

i have a few java micro services deployed on open shift . all of them are protected by a api-gateway application which uses keycloak for authentication & Authorization. 
Down stream services need to log which user perform certain actions.

in my api-gateway application properties i have already set zuul.sensitiveHeaders to empty

zuul.sensitiveHeaders:

i can see bearer token in the downstream applications . 
but how do i get the principal/user from token as downstream applications don't have keycloak dependency in gradle. ( if i add the dependency , i need to reconfigure realm and other properties ) .. is this the right way to do ?

i also tried adding a filter in api-gateway to separately set the user_name in header

@Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

```
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    System.out.println(" Filter doFilter "+req.getUserPrincipal());
    if(req.getUserPrincipal() != null ){
        res.setHeader("MYUSER",req.getUserPrincipal()==null?"NULL":req.getUserPrincipal().getName());
    }




    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

But when i try to get the header in downstream microservices is null.

Comment: You need to parse your token in those services and validate that the token is valid, has no expired, and if it does not contain any scopes, call a user info endpoint. Adding a header isn't secure anyone could call those headers with a request of MYUSER

Comment: i understand about security.. downstream applications are not exposed to external world. they are exposed only through api-gateway , using discoveryClient

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, or assuming that your non-web facing apps are completely secure. Realistically you should be re-validating the bearer token.

What you need is a zuul filter to add a header to the request. This is mostly from memory and you could update the filter to check if it should filter or not, that the request doesn't already contain an expected header etc.

```
@Component
public class AddUserHeader extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddUserHeader.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter{
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

       RequestContext.getCurrentContext().addZuulRequestHeader("MYUSER", SecurityContextHolder.getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getName());
       return null;
    }
```

Comment: Theny you have a different issue as this is how to add headers to zuul requests. Have you checked that the SecurityContextHolder actually has an authentication object to get your user from it? Have you debugged your filter to ensure it's actually being hit as part of the zuul route?

Comment: i can see the bearer token in downstream microservice by printing headers.  when i add    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}"    to gradle and try to acces the same URL i get error         "timestamp":1533673747163,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/about"}

Comment: because spring security locks down everything by default and it is up to you to open up the endpoints to whatever granularity you wish. I would seriously suggest you spend time reading the spring security documentation.

Comment: I have spring security setup @ API gateway level.  

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Loading security configuration");
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('user')"); // everything is restricted
    }

Authentication works fine .. all the microservices can be only invoked using api-gateway through discovery client.
I just need user info in downstream applications. what is the best way to get it